# List of member variables in a class.

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get a list of member variables of a class.

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title='Inferno'
        self.author = 'Dan Brown'
        self.publisher= 'DoubleDay'
        self.pages=480

bk = Book()
p=bk.__dict__
print p.keys()
```

The output is:

```
['publisher', 'author', 'pages', 'title']
```

I am curious here as the list is neither printedalphabetically nor according to the way I listed the class variables. So in what way does python print it out?

Comment: FTR in Python 3 you can do this: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclass-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its completely arbitrary, because it is a dictionary, and a dict is unordered.

(Well, not arbitrary, but more-or-less random, according to the way the computer stores the data).

Answer (score 1):

Python stores class variables in a `dict`. This is an unordered data structure, so Python is free to choose whatever order it likes.